# Orbot, android, is there a way to forbid apps to connect outside Tor?

Tags: orbot

I use **Orbot** on rooted android phone, I set it to „**Tor everything**“.

I want all apps to go through tor network or not connect at all.
Now, I use wifi connection that sometimes disconnects, how can I be sure that Firefox app and other apps don't go to clearnet in that short period of time when Orbot is making a connection to Tor network?

is there a way to forbid all apps to connect if Orbot is not connected?

Answer (score 1):

If Orbot is already connected, and your Wi-Fi is disconnected for a short period, Orbot will either wait for a connection, or attempt to establish circuits via your mobile connection if your device has one. Apps will not be able to use the clearnet if this happens.

However, some apps *may* be able to use the clearnet while your device is booting, before Orbot gets a chance to set `iptables`. I'm guessing you could fix that by manually editing `iptables`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Just one 100% fail-safe way: use routing middlebox, that will be a hotspot which routes all the traffic through Tor. Other ways suffer from "jailbreaks", especially on boot-up - check with Wireshark/tcpdump